# Formatting wx.TextCtrl with numeric values only - float precision

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have created a simple app which uses bare TextCtrl widgets with wxFILTER_NUMERIC in order to accept only numerical values (see code below).

I want the values to have a fixed display precision irrespective of how user inputs them (e.g. will always show 17.0000 in case of 17.0 or 17.000000 values being specified). I found that in wxPython there is an option to use a derived NumCtrl widget (http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.masked.numctrl-module.html) which does the job but I can't find it in the basic wxWidgets libraries.

So, is there a ready solution for this available somewhere which I simply cannot find or do I have to write a function which will change the format of the number manually once it has been inserted (handling EVT_TEXT and EVT_TEXT_ENTER events and modifying the input string)?

What I have so far:

**Event table**

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame) 
    EVT_MENU(ID_Quit, MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_MENU(ID_About, MyFrame::OnAbout)
    EVT_TEXT(ID_textBox, MyFrame::ValueChanged)
    EVT_TEXT_ENTER(ID_textBox, MyFrame::ValueChanged)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

**Implementation of the text box inside MyFrame**

```
wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, -1);

    _textBox1 = new wxTextCtrl(panel,
         ID_textBox, 
         "0.0000", 
         wxPoint(100, 100), 
         wxSize(80,20),
         wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER,
         wxTextValidator(wxFILTER_NUMERIC,&_myValue),
         wxTextCtrlNameStr);
```

**Handling function**

```
void MyFrame::ValueChanged(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    // modify the string or do something clever
}
```

**SOLUTION ADOPTED**
Thanks to the answer the problem has been resolved. Here's what I went with:

`

```
wxFloatingPointValidator<double> _val(2,&_myValue,wxNUM_VAL_ZERO_AS_BLANK);
    _val.SetRange(0.,100.);     // set allowable range

_textBox1 = new wxTextCtrl(panel,   // create a textCtrl
     ID_textBox, 
     "0.0000", 
     wxPoint(100, 30), 
     wxSize(80,20),
     wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER,
     _val,          // associate the text box with the desired validator
     wxTextCtrlNameStr);
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [wxFloatingPointValidator](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_floating_point_validator.html) available in wxWidgets 2.9.

Comment: Hi, I'll upgrade to 2.9 (I'm currently using 2.8.12) and will see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks! It works perfectly, just what I wanted. (I had some problems upgrading to 2.9.4 release from my 2.8.12, hence the late answer). Cheers.